# Calculating time until first steering correction

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, analysis

I have data from a driving experiment. Attached is a picture of my dataframe as an example. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMPg1.png)

So far I currently have code that splits my dataframe by the participant ID and trial number column, searches through the steering wheel angle (SWA) column and selects the first row where the steering angle is above a deadzone threshold and saves this to a new dataframe - one for each trial:

```
pilot_clean_new <- lapply(split(pilot_clean, list(pilot_clean$ppid, pilot_clean$trialn), drop = TRUE), function(data) {

i <- data[abs(data$SWA) > 0.01,] # find all observations that exceed threshold

if (nrow(i)==0) return(NULL) # handle cases where no observations meet critera

return(i[1,]) # return only the first match
})

pilot_clean_new <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, pilot_clean_new)
pilot_clean_new <- arrange(pilot_clean_new, ppid)
```

However as you can now see from this image of pilot_clean_new [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Dcj.png)

My timestamp was continuous. Thus I have the timestamp for each trial that the steering wheel angle was above threshold. What I would need is to subtract this timestamp from the first timestamp of each trial number, for each participant to get the "time elapsed" when the steering angle was above threshold.

Does anybody have any suggestions of how this would be possible? My idea was to use the original dataset and with some form of loop, select the first timestamp of each trial using head() and subtract this from my current timestamps in the clean dataframe.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, [edit] your question and provide a sample dataset and the expected result to reproduce your issue. Please, see also the hints in [mcve]. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated a sample data set that I believe to replicate the conditions required. Please advise if otherwise.

I used dplyr to execute the majority of functionality:

```
# load required libraries
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

# generate sample data
pilot_clean <- 
    base::data.frame(
        ppid = base::c(base::rep(1,15), base::rep(2,15), base::rep(3,15))
        , trialn = base::c(base::rep(1:3,15))
        , SWA = base::sample(base::seq(0.00,0.02, by = .001), 45, replace = T)
    ) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(ppid,trialn) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(timestamp = base::sort(stats::runif(45,min=5, max=125)))

# set threshold
SWA_threshold = 0.01

# force null condition
pilot_clean[pilot_clean$ppid == 3 & pilot_clean$trialn == 3,"SWA"] <- SWA_threshold - .001

# determine first time in each ppid, trialn group
pilot_clean_first_time <-
    pilot_clean %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(ppid,trialn) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number() == 1) %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup()  %>% 
    dplyr::transmute(ppid, trialn, first_timestamp = timestamp) #use transmute to rename for future join, ungroup first to allow for column rename of grouping variable

# determine first time in each ppid, trialn group above threshold
pilot_clean_first_time_above_threshold <-
    pilot_clean %>%
    dplyr::group_by(ppid,trialn) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(SWA > SWA_threshold) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number() == 1) %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
    dplyr::transmute(ppid, trialn, first_timestamp_above_threshold = timestamp) #use transmute to rename for future join, ungroup first to allow for column rename of grouping variable

# get unique list of ppid and trialn (to enable left join and null condition)
pilot_ppid_trial_list <- 
    pilot_clean %>% 
    dplyr::select(ppid,trialn) %>% 
    unique()

# produce final result set with ppid, trialn, first time, and first time above threshold
pilot_clean_new <-
    pilot_ppid_trial_list %>% 
    dplyr::left_join(pilot_clean_first_time) %>% 
    dplyr::left_join(pilot_clean_first_time_above_threshold) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(adjusted_first_timestamp_above_threshold = first_timestamp_above_threshold - first_timestamp) # calculate final result
```

Comment: This is great! I had eventually worked out how to do it, but using dplyr like you have is far more efficient. Thank you for this advice!